# Why Flink uses Akka for rpc?

Tags: akka, apache-flink

Akka programs are more difficult to debug. We will also need to track states of many actors to diagnose problem. Any explanation on why Flink chose Akka?

Comment: Why do you believe akka programs are more difficult to debug? How is tracking the state of multiple actors any different than tracking the state of multiple objects?

Answer (score 9):

The Flink project decided to use Akka for its underlying RPC service implementation because Akka can do most of the heavy lifting for you. Akka allows to easily implement asynchronous RPCs, supports enterprise features such as encryption and reaches a decent message throughput.

Note, however, that independent of the used RPC system, you always have to monitor multiple components and potentially correlate different log files if you want to debug a distributed system. This is an inherent problem of distributed data processing frameworks.

Moreover, the Akka rpc service implemenation `AkkaRpcService` is just one implementation of Flink's `RpcService`. There is no fundamental reason why one couldn't replace the `AkkaRpcService` implementation with an implementation based on a different networking library such as [Aeron](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron), for example.